# While Loop till valid user input - goes on indefinite

Tags: python

I am trying to use the While loop to validate a user response. I want user to enter "Y" or "N" to continue and kepe asking until a valid response is sought using while loop. I aks for user response within block and I am not using break as i am thinking having a valid response shoud break out of loop automatically. Despite receiving valid user response, the while loop keeps going.
Below is my code

`enter code here`

```
fruit_list = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "gooseberry", "kumquat", "orange", "pineapple"]
find = "Y"

while find == "Y":
    fruit_found = False
    print(fruit_list)
    fruit = input("Enter the fruit you want to find in the list above: ").lower()
    n=0
    for i in fruit_list:
        if fruit == fruit_list[n] and fruit_found==False:
            
            print("the fruit you are searching is on position", n+1, "in the fruit list")
            fruit_found = True    
        else:
            n+=1
                        
    if fruit_found == False:
        print("the fruit you are searching is not in the list")        
    
    find = input("Do you want to find another fruit? Enter Y for Yes and N for No: ").upper()   

    #work in progress to validate the response to continue. Y or N
    
    **while find != "Y" or "N" :
            print("Entered response is not valid. ")
            find = input("Test Do you want to find another fruit? Enter Y for Yes and N for No: ").upper()**
    
    
print("Thank you")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/3001761

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: `find != "Y" or "N"` is not doing what you hope it does. Though `find not in ("Y", "N")` might.

Comment: sorry this is my first time posting, i am not quite sure how this forum works, i tried editting but still seem to not show the entire post and code.

Comment: the problem i am facing is with this while loop. I would have thought that having a valid response would exit the loop, but it keep iterating.:                                        
      while find != "Y" or "N" :
            print("Entered response is not valid. ")
            find = input("Test Do you want to find another fruit? Enter Y for Yes and N for No: ").upper()

Comment: @JonSG Yes "find not in ("Y", "N")" surely worked exactly as i wanted. Thanks a lot. What was happening with the way i was trying to do?

Comment: A couple of others have posted links that will answer that. The quick and dirty answer is the `or "N"` part is not connected to `find` it is being interpreted as a stand alone test and any non-empty string (such as `"N"`) is "truthy". :-)

Comment: `find != "Y" or "N"` is interpreted as `(find != "Y") or ("N")`, and `"N"` being treated as `True`, the condition for the `while`-loop was always `True`.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Very helpful. so glad to receive amazing support. So glad to have joined this community.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to work for you:

`while find not in ["Y", "N"]: print("Entered response is not valid. ") find = input("Test Do you want to find another fruit? Enter Y for Yes and N for No: ").upper()`

Basically you are asking if the "find" variable equals "Y" or if "N" is an empty string - which obviously is not true. You can also do it that way:

```
while find != "Y" and find != "N":
```